# How to run queries on EMR Hive from NodeJS and Lambda

Tags: node.js, hive, amazon-dynamodb, emr, bigdata

I created 2 `EXTERNAL TABLE` in `EMR` with mapping to `DynamoDB`. The table names are **Attributes** and **AttributeTypes**.

In Attribute, I store `id` of **AttributeType** as `attributeTypeId`.

How I want to run query on the EMR hive from my NodeJS application incluging JOIN, WHERE, ORDER and LIMIT. How can I do it from the NodeJS application. So far I have only been successful runing queries from the AWS CLI, and can find nothing in the AWS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I never tested this with EMR connection. But you can try to find the connection.

There is at PrestoDb [documentation](https://prestodb.io/resources.html) few options to connect to Hive and PrestoDb with a tons of languages. I suggest you to see the [shib](https://github.com/tagomoris/shib) this will connect to a Hive to do queries.

I hope this can give you a direction.